# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer request por GET a REST API?

Tags: api, reactjs

```js
var data = function (){
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/demos')  
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  })
}

class Content extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = data;
    }

    render() {
        let demosView = [];

        this.state.demos.forEach(function(demo){
            demosView.push(
                <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div className="hovereffect">
        <img className="img-responsive" src={imgdir + demo.img} alt={demo.name} />
            <div className="overlay">
                <h2>{demo.name}</h2>
                <p> 
                    <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec blandit nibh. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla vitae eleifend leo, sed gravida nulla.</b>
                </p> 
                <p> 
                    <a href="#">VIEW DEMO</a>
                </p> 
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {demosView}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer este request por GET a mi REST API?

Answer (score 1):

El estado de un componente React es un objeto javascript y este almacena la información mutable del componente, con mutable se refiere a la información que va a cambiar en el componente.

Esto es un objeto javascript

```
{
  nombre: 'Juan',
  apellido: 'Perez'
  direccion: {
    callePrimaria: 'Avenida siempre viva 123',
    calleSecundaria: 'La que cruza'
  }
}
```

La estructura la puedes ver como una estructura tipo Clave -> Valor o {clave: 'valor'}, como valor puedes tener numeros, decimales, otros objetos o incluso funciones, pero estrictamente hablando de un componente React debes limitarte a tener numeros, cadenas, booleanos, decimales y objetos como valores y evita usar funciones como en tu ejemplo donde inicializas el estado asignando una función directamente.

```
this.state = data;
```

En tu código la variable data es una función no un objeto por lo tanto no debes asignarlo al state, el state es la representación del estado del componente por lo tanto no debes asignar una función ya que al hacerlo estarías almacenando comportamiento en lugar de estado.

Lo que debes hacer es mirar a tu componente React como una representación visual de determinado estado de tu aplicación. En tu caso el estado es la información de un listado de 'demos'. por lo tanto es este listado obtenido de la solicitud ajax el que debe ser asignado al state del componente, no la función que realiza la llamada ajax en sí.

Entonces por default el listado de demos debe estar vacío. y puedes utilizar el método componentDidMount del componente React como punto de partida para realizar la petición Ajax al servidor solicitando el listado de demos, al obtener el listado de demos entonces **mutas** el estado del componente actualizando el listado que renderiza el componente.

```
class Content extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            demos: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/demos')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(demos) {
                self.setState({demos: demos})
            });
    }

    render() {
        let demosView = [];

        this.state.demos.forEach(function(demo){
            demosView.push(
                <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div className="hovereffect">
                        <img className="img-responsive" src={imgdir + demo.img} alt={demo.name} />
                        <div className="overlay">
                            <h2>{demo.name}</h2>
                            <p>
                                <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec blandit nibh. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla vitae eleifend leo, sed gravida nulla.</b>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#">VIEW DEMO</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {demosView}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

Siempre debes usar el metodo setState del componente React para mutar (modificar) su estado, de esta manera React sabe que debe modificar el atributo state y también fuerzas a que el método render se ejecute lo cual actualiza la vista y puede visualizar los cambios en el DOM.